# How to sum the each file data with each files in particular directory perl?

Tags: perl

How to sum the one file with each file perl my file data like this

File1

```
1
23
12
43
```

File2

```
1
98
11
3
```

File3

```
12
113
34
24
```

File4

```
12
143
123
1
```

I tried to try this:

```
$dir = 'd:\occ';
opendir (file,"$dir");
@eachfile = grep{m/.*\.txt/g} readdir (file);

for ($i = 0; $i<=scalar @eachfile; $i++){
    for ($j=0; $j<=scalar @eachfile; $j++){
        open(fil1,"$dir/$i");
        open(fil2,"$dir/$j");
        @ar = <fil1>;
        @br = <fil2>;
        my $tot;
        $tot+=$_,foreach (@ar);
        $divide = $tot/4;
        my $tot2;
        $tot2+=$_,foreach (@br);
        $divide2 = $tot2/4;
        $ans = $divide+$divide2;
        print "$i + $j = $ans\n";
    }
}
```

I expect each file is add and divid by four. Then the each values are add with another data. 
Finally 16 outputs are calculate by this code How can i do it. I expect output is

```
1 + 1 = 39.5
1 + 2 = 48
1 + 3 = 65.75
1 + 4 = 89.5
2 + 1 = 48
2 + 2 = 56.5
... and so on
4 + 3 = 115.5
4 + 4 = 139.5
```

Totally 16 outputs are calculate

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: [`List::Util::sum`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#$num_or_undef-=-sum-@list) might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to find the average value of each file.

```
open(my $fh, '<', $file_name) or die $!;

my $sum;
my $count;
while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   $sum += $_;
   ++$count;
}

$avgs{$file_name} = $sum/$count;
```

This gives you

```
my %avgs = (
   'File1' => (1+23+12+43)/4,
   'File2' => (1+98+11+3)/4,
   'File3' => (12+113+34+24)/4,
   'File4' => (12+143+123+1)/4,
);
```

Now, you want to add each element with itself and each subsequent element in turn. That's simply two nested loops.

```
my @file_names = sort keys %avgs;

for my $i (0..$#file_names) {
   for my $j ($i..$#file_names) {
      print "$file_names[$i] + $file_names[$j] = ",
         $file_names[$i] + $file_names[$j], "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question with some mistakes, so only any body don't understand my question. I solve a problem.

```
 $dir = 'd:\occ';
 opendir (file,"$dir");
 @eachfile = grep{m/.*\.txt/g} readdir (file);
 for ($i=0; $i<=scalar @eachfile; $i++){
    for ($j=0; $j<= scalar @eachfile; $j++){
        open(fil1,"$dir/$eachfile[$i]");
        open(fil2,"$dir/$eachfile[$j]");
        @ar = <fil1>;
        @br = <fil2>;
        my $tot;
        $tot+=$_,foreach (@ar);
        $divide = $tot/4;
        my $tot1;
        $tot1+=$_,foreach (@br);
        $divid = $tot1/4;
        $ans = $divide + $divid;

        print "$i + $j  = $ans\n";
    }

 }
```

In this script prints the output which i expect.